How to Mirror Azure Cosmos DB documents having both id and Id fields into Fabric consistently
Azure CosmosDB requires every document to have an id property.  I am saving documents received from a 3rd party which can contain an Id field.  This does not cause any problems with CosmosDB.  id is used when interacting with Comsmos documents, Id is used by downstream services expecting this property.  I have a DEV cosmos account and PROD cosmos account. I am trying to mirror the cosmos db into Fabric, but Fabric does not like having two id properties that only vary by case so it takes one of them and adds _1.  Is there a way to make it always choose id => id_1 and/or is there a way to change this so id => _id instead and Id always remains as Id?
What is happening now is DEV mirror selected id => id_1, but PROD mirror selected Id => Id_1.  I'm assuming because the first document imported to PROD did not contain an Id field, but DEV did.  Because of this difference, the first layer of views in the data warehouse that query this table have to select a different field for the Id field that downstream systems are expecting.  For now, I'm just manually tweaking the scripts and running them directly, but I would love to use source control and Schema Compare for both environments.
